# How to rename tables in microsoft access using vba / macro?

Tags: ms-access

I have an ms access database with 24 tables. I need to rename the tables every day from

```
table 1 --> table 1backup
```

any ideas will be appreciated.

Is it doable with VBA?

Comment: Sounds like a hideous design. Why do you think you need to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can:

```
Dim tdf As TableDef

For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
    If Left(tdf.Name, 4) <> "MSys" Then
      tdf.Name = tdf.Name & "_backup"
    End If
Next
```

Comment: How might this be adapted to rename a single table?

Comment: `CurrentDb.TableDefs("mytablename").Name = "mynewtablename"`

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest below code. It would replace newly renamed table, with the existed table, if already has existed with the new table name:

```
Dim tdf As TableDef
For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
    If Left(tdf.Name, 7) <> "backup_" Then

        Dim newTableName As String
        newTableName = "backup_" + tdf.Name

        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.Rename newTableName, acTable, tdf.Name
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    End If

Next
```